# Access token for Azure Active Directory using azure-cli

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a web app on Azure App Service that requires Azure Active Directory authentication.  I can connect receive an access token for the secured app from within other apps using either the [OAuth 2.0 flow for service-to-service communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) or [Managed Service Identity (MSI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/msi-overview).

For MSI Microsoft provides a library,[Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication) , for authentication that also supports using the credentials from the `azure-cli` tool.

However, the library is currently in preview and it does not work on my system, but I managed to find its [source code on github](https://github.com/varunsh-msft/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/AppAuthentication).

The [relevant part](https://github.com/varunsh-msft/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/AppAuthentication/src/SdkCommon/AppAuthentication/Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/TokenProviders/AzureCliAccessTokenProvider.cs) seems to call

`$ az account get-access-token <resource>`

However, when I try it with the resource name of the app I am trying to access I get the following error:

`Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID <application id> named <application name>.`

For the resource name I tried both the App ID URI and Client ID.

Has anyone managed to use `azure-cli` to get an access token in a similar scenario?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/healthcare-apis/get-healthcare-apis-access-token-cli.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that you need to consent to that application (the CLI) accessing that API (the scope/resource).

The fastest way to do this would be to build a URL for consent for the CLI to let you consent to the CLI accessing your application. The cli app id is `04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46`.

Something like this.

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your-tenant-name-or-id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46&scope=<the scope of the target app/api>`